# Incremental archive and restoration of partial Postgresql tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am wondering what are the best practices to:

1. Periodically (monthly) archive a portion of a Postgresql table to a `.sql` file
2. Then have the ability to restore that portion to the original table if necessary

For example, say I have `transactions_table` that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| Id |    Date    | Transaction |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2017-06-01 |         123 |
|  2 | 2017-06-02 |         120 |
|  3 | 2017-07-01 |          45 |
|  4 | 2017-08-01 |         420 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

How would I go about archiving data for June of 2017 such that all data from June 2017 is removed from `transactions_table` and I produce a `June2017.sql` file that contains insert commands and all other information so it can easily be reintroduced to `transactions_table`?
Is this possible with `pg_dump` or is there a better alternative?

The Postgresql db is v9.6 and hosted by AWS. I plan to store the `June2017.sql` and such either within an S3 bucket or long term storage such as AWS Glacier. I can figure that part out. Just need to know how to to archive the data appropriately.

Sorry for broad question. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `pg_dump` doesn't support a `WHERE` out of the box. But [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1216999182.3894.930.camel%40ebony.2ndQuadrant) somebody provided a patch, that introduces this functionality. You can try if that works for you.
2. An alternative would be to write a function, that creates a new table, say `archive_transactions_table` and `pg_dump` that table.

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION create_archive_transactions_table
                   (_year integer,
                    _month integer)
                   RETURNS void
   AS
   $$
   BEGIN
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS archive_transactions_table;
     CREATE TABLE archive_transactions_table
                  AS SELECT *
                            FROM transactions_table
                            WHERE date_part('year', date) = _year
                                  AND date_part('month', date) = _month;
   END;
   $$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```
3. You could also roll your own `INSERT` statements by text concatenation. You could then select these from the `transactions_table` for the rows withing the time period. Possibly put it in a function using `COPY` to directly export the made up statements to a file. `COPY`does support `WHERE` (or a query in general) but doesn't create `INSERT` statements by it's own.

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION archive_transactions_table
                   (_year integer,
                    _month integer,
                    _path text)
                   RETURNS void
   AS
   $$
   DECLARE
     _copy_command text;
   BEGIN
     _copy_command := 'COPY (SELECT ''INSERT INTO transactions_table (id, date, transaction) VALUES ('' || id || '', '''''' || date || '''''', '' || transaction || '');'' insert_query'
                   || '             FROM transactions_table'
                   || '             WHERE date_part(''year'', date) = ' || _year
                   || '                   AND date_part(''month'', date) = ' || _month || ')'
                   || 'TO ''' || regexp_replace(_path, '([^/])$', '\1/') || _year || '-' || lpad(_month::text, 2, '0') || '.sql''';
     EXECUTE _copy_command;
   END;
   $$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```

   (Note: The path provided to `COPY` cannot be an expression (like `_year || '-' || _month || '.sql`). That's why the whole command has to be build up dynamically.)

Or any possible mix of the above.

Have a look at pgAgent for creating a scheduled task.